# Define interval $M$ for inequality $(x^2+y^2)^2\leq2y^3$ and calculate integral $\iint_M1dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I first thought I could use polar substitution where $\phi$ would be $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$, but I couldn't figure out the bounds for the radius.

I think it would be better to just define it normally where:
$$0\leq y\leq2$$
$$-\sqrt{-y^2+\sqrt{2y^3}}\leq x\leq\sqrt{-y^2+\sqrt{2y^3}}$$

But I have to note that considering the shape, I can define the bounds for $x$ to be $0\leq x\leq\sqrt{-y^2+\sqrt{2y^3}}$ and double the integral $\iint_M2dxdy$.

I therefore get the double integral:

$$2\int_0^2\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{-y^2+\sqrt{2y^3}}}1dx\right)dy$$

Solve the inner one:

$$2\int_0^2\sqrt{-y^2+\sqrt{2y^3}}dy$$

$$2\int_0^2\sqrt{-y^2+y\sqrt{2y}}dy$$

Then substitution for $y=u^2$ so $dy = 2udu$:

$$4\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{-u^4+u^2\sqrt{2u^2}}udu$$

$$4\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{-u^4+\sqrt{2}u^3}udu$$

$$4\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{u^2\left(-u^2+\sqrt{2}u\right)}udu$$

$$4\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}u^2\sqrt{-u^2+\sqrt{2}u}du$$

And I'm not sure where to go from here. I think using polar coorinates should be easier, I just have to find the bounds for $r$.

Comment: You definitely want to use polar coordinates.  You can replace $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = (r^2)^2$ and $2y^3 = 2r^3\sin^3\theta$, so that
$$r^4 \le 2r^3\sin^3\theta \Longleftrightarrow r \le 2\sin^3\theta.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue with the substitution $ y=\sqrt2 u-1$
\begin{align}
I=&\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}4 u^2\sqrt{-u^2+\sqrt{2}u}\ du\\
=&\int_{-1}^1(1+y)^2 (1-y^2)^{1/2}\ dy
=\int_{-1}^1 -(1-y^2)^{3/2}+2(y+1) (1-y^2)^{1/2}\ dy
\end{align}
and note that
\begin{align}
&\int_{-1}^1 (1-y^2)^{3/2}dy= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-y^2)^{3/2}} {4y^3}d(y^4)\overset{ibp}=\frac34 \int_{-1}^1 (1-y^2)^{1/2}\ dy\\
 &\int_{-1}^1 (1-y^2)^{1/2}dy= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-y^2)^{1/2}} {2y}d(y^2)\overset{ibp}=\frac12\int_{-1}^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\ dy
\end{align}
Plug into above $I$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I
=&\int_{-1}^1 2y\sqrt{1-y^2}+\frac58\frac1{\sqrt{1-y^2} }\ dy
=\left(-\frac23 (1-y^2)^{3/2}+\frac58 \sin^{-1}y \right)\bigg|_{-1}^1= \frac{5\pi}8
\end{align}